# Multi-step form in animated div/fieldset

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a step-by-step walkthrough. Each step is enclosed in a separate "fieldset", and the whole is a single .html file.

To move forward and back I use javascript.
The problem is that over time, animations are beginning to lag.

In the attached example everything works smoothly, because there is little content.
Where is the problem with optimization?

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venntr/1x183c2t/9/)

HTML:

```
 <form id="msform">
             <fieldset id="firstField">   
                      <input type="button" name="subject1" class="next action-button" value="Subject1 />
<input type="button" name="subject2" class="next action-button" value="Subject2 />
<input type="button" name="subject3" class="next action-button" value="Subject3 />
             </fieldset>
             <fieldset id="subject1">
            <h2>Some text</h2>
            <input type="button" name="prev" class="back action-button" value="Back" />
            <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Reset" />
         </fieldset>
    </form>
```

Javascript:

```
  var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs, back_fs;
     var left, opacity, scale;
     var animating;
     var progress = [];
     var message = "Funkcja niedostępna.";
     $(".next").click(function() {
         if (animating) return false;
         animating = true;
         current_fs = $(this).parent();
         next_fs = $('#' + $(this).attr('name'));

         $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");
         progress.push($('fieldset:visible'));

         next_fs.show();
         current_fs.animate({
             opacity: 0
         }, {
             step: function(now, mx) {
                 scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
                 left = (now * 50) + "%";
                 opacity = 1 - now;
                 next_fs.css({
                     'left': left,
                     'opacity': opacity
                 });
             },
             duration: 800,
             complete: function() {
                 current_fs.hide();
                 animating = false;
             },
             easing: 'easeInOutBack'
         });
     });
     $(".previous").click(function() {
         if (animating) return false;
         animating = true;
         current_fs = $(this).parent();
         previous_fs = $('#firstField');

         $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(current_fs)).removeClass("active");

         previous_fs.show();
         current_fs.animate({
             opacity: 0
         }, {
             step: function(now, mx) {
                 scale = 0.8 + (1 - now) * 0.2;
                 left = ((1 - now) * 50) + "%";
                 opacity = 1 - now;
                 current_fs.css({
                     'left': left
                 });
                 previous_fs.css({
                     'transform': 'scale(' + scale + ')',
                     'opacity': opacity
                 });
             },
             duration: 800,
             complete: function() {
                 current_fs.hide();
                 animating = false;
             },
             easing: 'easeInOutBack'
         });
     });
     $(".back").click(function() {
         if (animating) return false;
         animating = true;
         current_fs = $(this).parent();
         $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(current_fs)).removeClass("active");

         back_fs = progress.pop();
         back_fs.show();
         current_fs.animate({
             opacity: 0
         }, {
             step: function(now, mx) {
                 scale = 0.8 + (1 - now) * 0.2;
                 left = ((1 - now) * 50) + "%";
                 opacity = 1 - now;
                 current_fs.css({
                     'left': left
                 });
                 back_fs.css({
                     'transform': 'scale(' + scale + ')',
                     'opacity': opacity
                 });
             },
             duration: 800,
             complete: function() {
                 current_fs.hide();
                 animating = false;
             },
             easing: 'easeInOutBack'
         });
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

Were you ever able to make the button work in a div?

I downloaded the same "Multi Step Form with Progress Bar using jQuery and CSS3".

I was able to show the fieldsets with divs but the actual button... the onclick doesn't work unless outside a div.

so while this proceeds to next step

```
  <fieldset>
<h2 class="fs-title">Create your account</h2>
<h3 class="fs-subtitle">This is step 1</h3>
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
<input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password" />
<input type="password" name="cpass" placeholder="Confirm Password" />
<input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
```

while this one does not

```
  <fieldset>
<h2 class="fs-title">Create your account</h2>
<h3 class="fs-subtitle">This is step 1</h3>
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
<input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password" />
<input type="password" name="cpass" placeholder="Confirm Password" />
<div class="pull-right">
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />                
</div>
```

there is nothing I haven't tried... even removing the animations didn't work

In answer to your question... :)

I changed my JS to disable (comment out) as much animation as possible and made the duration 000...

```
//jQuery time
var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets
var opacity; //fieldset properties which we will animate
var animating; //flag to prevent quick multi-click glitches

$(".next").click(function(){
    if(animating) return false;
    animating = true;

    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    next_fs = $(this).parent().next();

    //activate next step on progressbar using the index of next_fs
    $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");

    //show the next fieldset
    next_fs.show(); 
    //hide the current fieldset with style
    current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
        step: function(now, mx) {
            //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
            //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
            //scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
            //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
            //left = (now * 50)+"%";
            //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
            opacity = 1 - now;
            //current_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')'});
            current_fs.css({'opacity': opacity});
            //next_fs.css({'left': left, 'opacity': opacity});
            next_fs.css({'opacity': opacity});
        }, 
        duration: 000, 
        complete: function(){
            current_fs.hide();
            animating = false;
        }, 
        //this comes from the custom easing plugin
        easing: 'easeInOutBack'
    });
});

$(".previous").click(function(){
    if(animating) return false;
    animating = true;

    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    previous_fs = $(this).parent().prev();

    //de-activate current step on progressbar
    $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(current_fs)).removeClass("active");

    //show the previous fieldset
    previous_fs.show(); 
    //hide the current fieldset with style
    current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
        step: function(now, mx) {
            //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
            //1. scale previous_fs from 80% to 100%
            //scale = 0.8 + (1 - now) * 0.2;
            //2. take current_fs to the right(50%) - from 0%
            //left = ((1-now) * 50)+"%";
            //3. increase opacity of previous_fs to 1 as it moves in
            opacity = 1 - now;
            //current_fs.css({'left': left});
            current_fs.css({'opacity': opacity});
            //previous_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')', 'opacity': opacity});
            previous_fs.css({'opacity': opacity});
        }, 
        duration: 000, 
        complete: function(){
            current_fs.hide();
            animating = false;
        }, 
        //this comes from the custom easing plugin
        easing: 'easeInOutBack'
    });
});
```